# Is there a preferred way to store multiselect values?

Tags: python, data-structures, structure

I need to store data coming from a multiselect dropdown menu and thinking about what data structure is the simplest and best for storage of such values. I had several ideas of how to store the values but I am asking if there is some preferred pythonic way how to solve this (e.g. some class for multiselect structure).

```
#1)
fruits=["Apple","Pear","Apricot","Banana","Orange","Raspberry","Blueberry","Kiwi","Pineapple"]
chosen_fruit_indices=[2,4,5] 
#problem1: need to update indices when fruit list is updated

#2)
fruits=["Apple","Pear","Apricot","Banana","Orange","Raspberry","Blueberry","Kiwi","Pineapple"]
chosen_fruits=["Apricot","Orange","Raspberry"] 
#problem2: need to be updated when fruit list does not contain one of chosen items anymore

#3)
fruits=["Apple","Pear","Apricot","Banana","Orange","Raspberry","Blueberry","Kiwi","Pineapple"]
chosen_fruit_dict={"Apricot":True,"Orange":True,"Raspberry":True}
#problem2: need to be updated when fruit list does not contain one of chosen items anymore
#problem3: problematic duplicate keys in dictionary

#4)
chosen_fruit_dict={"Apple":False,"Pear":False,"Apricot":True,"Banana":False,"Orange":True,"Raspberry":True,
                   "Blueberry":False,"Kiwi":False,"Pineapple":False}
#problem3: problematic duplicate keys in dictionary
#advantage1: one variable is enough to store all the information
```

Comment: In my experience, most websites I’ve seen make use of option 4.

Comment: Yes, but then the duplicate keys are problem, also ordering of the fruits. Then it comes to try something like [["Apple",False],["Pear",False]...] or use list of dicts, but I wanted to avoid using nested lists.

Comment: `for fruit in fruits: if chosen_fruit_dict[fruit]: # Do stuff` What's the issue with that?

Comment: With the dict approach you can't have multiple fruits, like ["Apple","Apple","Apple","Pear"] (imagine it as an inventory and you want to drop multiple items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the question I came up with a new package tackling all: duplicate values; fast subsetting of ticked and unticked items; and ordered adding and removing of items.

It can be found here: https://github.com/DovaX/multiselect

One can easily install it with

```
pip install multiselect
```

The usage is the following

```
from multiselect.multiselect_core import Multiselect

fruits=["Apple","Pear","Apricot","Banana","Orange","Raspberry","Blueberry","Kiwi","Pineapple"]

fruit_multiselect=[{"key":"Apple","value":False},{"key":"Pear","value":False},{"key":"Apricot","value":True},{"key":"Banana","value":False},
                   {"key":"Orange","value":True},{"key":"Raspberry","value":True},{"key":"Kiwi","value":False},{"key":"Pineapple","value":False}]


multiselect=Multiselect(fruit_multiselect) #1st way how to initialize

multiselect2=Multiselect.init_from_options(fruits) #2nd way how to initialize
multiselect2.tick_by_indices([2,4,5])

multiselect3=Multiselect.init_from_options(fruits) #3rd way how to initialize
multiselect3.tick_all_by_key("Apricot")
multiselect3.tick_all_by_key("Orange")
multiselect3.tick_all_by_key("Raspberry")

multiselect4=Multiselect.init_from_options(fruits) #4th way how to initialize
multiselect4.tick_all_by_keys(["Apricot","Orange","Raspberry"])


print(multiselect.data)
#[{'key': 'Apple', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Pear', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Apricot', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Banana', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Orange', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Raspberry', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Kiwi', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Pineapple', 'value': False}]

print(multiselect.keys())
#['Apple', 'Pear', 'Apricot', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Raspberry', 'Kiwi', 'Pineapple']

print(multiselect.values())
#[False, False, True, False, True, True, False, False]

print(multiselect)
#<Multiselect object> [{'key': 'Apple', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Pear', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Apricot', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Banana', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Orange', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Raspberry', 'value': True}, {'key': 'Kiwi', 'value': False}, {'key': 'Pineapple', 'value': False}]

print(multiselect["Apple"])
#False

print(multiselect.items())
#[('Apple', False), ('Pear', False), ('Apricot', True), ('Banana', False), ('Orange', True), ('Raspberry', True), ('Kiwi', False), ('Pineapple', False)]

print(multiselect.get_ticked_indices())
#[2, 4, 5]

print(multiselect.get_unticked_indices())
#[0, 1, 3, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which will allow you store multiple of each fruit efficiently:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
chosen_fruit_dict: dict[str, int]  # The fruit as the key and the number of them on the right
chosen_fruit_dict = OrderedDict({"Apple": 3, "Pear": 1, "Apricot": 2})
```

**Benefits:**

- **Easier to debug** - When debugging instead of getting a list akin to `["Apple","Apple","Apple","Pear"]` a neater `OrderedDict([('Apple', 3), ('Pear', 1)])` will help you clearly see what is going on with the players inventory
- **Retains the order of the items** - if the original `fruits` list was to change, changing the `chosen_fruit_dict` would not be as difficult to do
- **Still easy to access** -

  ```py
  for fruit in chosen_fruit_dict:
      # Do stuff here with every fruit
      for i in range(chosen_fruit_dict[fruit]):
          # Do stuff here with the number of that fruit
  ```
- **Could save a bit of memory** - If you ever need really long lists this would be scalable

**Drawbacks:**

- **Uses a little more computation at run-time** - should not even be significant enough to be noticeable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still it has issues if I allow for picking up of items overtime and I want to store the order of picking them up. Then ["Apple","Orange","Apple"] would not be equivalent to OrderedDict({"Apple": 2, "Orange": 1})